# Redisson-spring-boot-starter library fails to start the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, redisson

i am using Redisson-spring-boot-starter 3.17.0 and spring-boot version 2.7.1 below is my pom file , the application fails to start with the below dependencies.

I tried playing around with different versions but still same failure. Tried adding spring-data-26 and spring-session-data-redis along with redisson-spring-boot-starter dint help. Replaced the redisson spring boot starter dependency with just redisson, but that gave cacheManager bean not found error.

i am implementing Rate limiting using bucket4j and redis referring this implementation: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rate-limiting-with-bucket4j-and-redis/

> > 
>
> ```
> <revision>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
> <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
> <java.version>11</java.version>
> <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
> <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
> <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
> <mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</mapstruct.version>
> <micrometer.version>1.10.1</micrometer.version>
> <h2.version>2.1.210</h2.version>
> <jose4j.version>0.7.10</jose4j.version>
> <junit-jupiter.version>5.8.1</junit-jupiter.version>
> <springdoc.version>1.6.6</springdoc.version>
> <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
> <spring-boot-starter-security.version>2.6.3</spring-boot-starter-security.version>
> <!--Official plugins-->
> <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
> <maven-failsafe-plugin-version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</maven-failsafe-plugin-version>
> <git-commit-id-plugin.version>5.0.0</git-commit-id-plugin.version>
> <jacoco-plugin-version>0.8.7</jacoco-plugin-version>
> <spotless.version>2.20.2</spotless.version>
> <exists-maven-plugin.version>0.6.0</exists-maven-plugin.version>
> <google-java-format.version>1.13.0</google-java-format.version>
> <wagon-ssh-external.version>3.5.1</wagon-ssh-external.version>
> <bucket4j.version>0.5.2</bucket4j.version>   </properties>   <dependencies>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>   <exclusions>
>     <exclusion>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>     </exclusion>
>     <exclusion>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
>     </exclusion>
>   </exclusions>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
>   <optional>true</optional>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
>   <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
>   <version>${micrometer.version}</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
>   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
>   <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
>   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
>   <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
>   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
>   <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
>   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
>   <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
>   <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
>   <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
>   <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
>   <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
>   <optional>true</optional>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId>
>   <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId>
>   <version>${jose4j.version}</version>
> </dependency>
> <!-- Configuring Spring Boot to use Log4j2 -->
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
>   <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
>   <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
>   <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
>   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
>   <version>${h2.version}</version>
>   <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
>   <version>${spring-boot-starter-security.version}</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
>   <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
>   <artifactId>redisson-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
>   <version>3.17.0</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <!-- Bucket4J starter = Bucket4J + JCache -->
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.giffing.bucket4j.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
>   <artifactId>bucket4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
>   <version>0.5.2</version>
> </dependency>   </dependencies>
> ```

Comment: Can you share the exception?